# Camera Coordinate To Screen Coordinate

Tags: libgdx

I want to convert the camera coordinate to screen coordinate. I have asked this question because my camera is 48m wide and 32m high but my screen is 480x320 pixels. So whatever collision point I get those are based on camera. Also I like to mention that my camera set at center of the screen. So I get (0,0) coordinate at middle of the screen. At collision time I put some particle effect but now that particle effect not at correct place in the screen. So someone from community please help.

Answer (score 7):

How about using the project-method in the camera class.

```
camera.project(Vector3 worldPoint)
```

That projects the vector cameraPoint from world/camera coordinates into screen/window coordinates. The reverse method is camera.unproject(Vector3 screenPoint). Have a look at the [libgdx camera class](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Camera.html#project%28com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3%29).

Comment: This is the right way to do it +1 :D

Answer (score 2):

Taken from http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2032

I'm only assuming that this will help based on your question...

```
Ray pickRay = cam.getPickRay(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY());
Intersector.intersectRayPlane(pickRay, xzPlane, intersection);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to [translate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_%28geometry%29) the camera coordinates into viewspace.

In this particular case your Camera coordinates go from [-24,-16] to [24,16] and you want that to translate to [0,0] to [480,320].

Pseudo code:

```
view.X = camera.X * 10 + view.width / 2
view.Y = camera.Y * 10 + view.height / 2
```